# windows programming without a OOP language

Tags: windows, user-interface, procedural-programming

Which language ( that is not oop ) should I consider using for writing gui windows  apps ? 
I guess the obvious answers are visual basic and C , but am wondering if I should look into anything else

am not saying OOP sucks or anything. I just don't.. not using it. The END

ty

Edit: I just want a language that has a non oop paradigm option and that is/can be used to write a windows gui application .

Comment: Why is having an OO option in the language a problem? There are several languages that support both styles quite nicely. Even perl has some optional OO options theses days.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite possible to write procedural code in any language.

Comment: I decided to rethink things and have decided to stay with oop (c#) (atleast for my current application)

Answer (score 1):

There is [FreeBasic](http://www.freebasic.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally recommend giving Fortran a go, it's quite nice...

Comment: But not the newer versions, as they support OO too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Python. Sure it can be used in a OO way (as pretty much all other languages can as well), but it's pretty easy to write clean, simple, procedural code with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

C would be my choice, Visual Studio supports it and has an excellent debugger. There are also plenty of examples out on the web in C for Windows programming so you'll have the easiest time getting your code to work.

Answer (score 0):

OO is kind of a pervasive paradigm these days. It's pretty much impossible to avoid, even languages like VB and C can be used to program in an OO way, although I do get what you mean. Have you considered Fortran? COBOL? J? Perl? Python? They can all pretty much be used in a non OO way.

Not to mention assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

[F#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) I guess, avoiding its inherent object-oriented programming model. But do you like functional languages and the .NET framework?!

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, why do you need such a thing?

Windows programming is OO by design. Even if you use C, all the API functions work like OO.

Every handle has a corresponding Create function

CloseHandle if used to close any object, not just a specific type

And finally every single API function gets a Handle to a relevant object, just like the old implementation of OO in pure C with structs - the equivalent of this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are guys who are still using Visual Foxpro, or Visual Basic 6 (which is NOT OO, contrary to what some people say).

Answer (score 0):

C and Windows API. It is not OO, but feels like, because OO (C++, Java, C#) is nothing but making structs into objects.